# Resultado da Função é Exibido em Diversas Linhas

Tags: react

Preciso exibir o resultado da soma dos meus itens em apenas uma linha.

Fiz uma função para somar os valores dos de uma lista de objetos, o resultado da soma está dado certo porém ele precisa aparecer em apenas uma linha da minha tabela, agora ele está aparecendo em várias linhas.

Como posso resolver isso?

Obrigado!

Segue o código:

```js
<Table striped bordered hover variant="dark">
  <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>Resultado</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      {                           
        this.state.transacoes.map((item, indice)  => {
          var total = this.state.transacoes.reduce(getTotal, 0);
          
          function getTotal(total, item) {
            return total + (item.valor);
          }

          return (                                
            <tr key={indice}>
              <td> {total}</td>
            </tr>                                
            )
        })                         
      }
  </tbody>
</Table>
```

*Resultado do Código:*

[image: Resultado do Código]

Comment: Você tá fazendo o map dentro do `render` (ou `return` de um componente funcional). Por que não faz um `.forEach()`, calcula e depois cria uma linha com esse resultado?

Comment: @RafaelTavares é uma boa, mas acho que ele poderia usar o 'reduce' direto , sem precisar do 'map', dentro de uma 'IIFE'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguindo o comentario do `Rafael Tavares`, voçe pode fazer uma função que realiza um loop `forEach` no seu `state.transacoes` e a cada iteração do loop, vamos incrementar o valor de uma variavel chamada `total`.

Do jeito que voçê fez, será exibido um `<td>` a quantidade de item que tiver no seu `transacoes`, ou seja, se tiver 3 transacoes, serão exibidas 3 `td`, se tiver 5, 5 `td`, e assim por diante...

Eu indico essa alternativa que eu fiz. O que podes fazer seria tirar esse `map`, e usar o `reduce` diretamente dentro de uma [`IIFE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossario/IIFE).

Ficaria assim o código:

```js
<Table striped bordered hover variant="dark">
  <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>Resultado</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      { 
        (() => {
          var total = this.state.transacoes.reduce(getTotal, 0);

          function getTotal(total, item) {
            return total + (item.valor);
          }

          // agora vai retornar somente uma linha no table com o resultado total
          return (
              <tr key={Math.random()}>
              <td> {total}</td>
              </tr>
            )
        })()
      }
  </tbody>
</Table>
```

Teste este script e veja se esse é o comportamento esperado. Espero que eu tenha ajudado e que tenhas entendido o código.

Comment: Eu estava tentando fazer mas não estava conseguindo. Obrigado!